# Vintage Intercom BJT Preamplifier: Purpose of Capacitors and DC Bias Troubleshooting

Tags: amplifier, dc, bjt, bias, troubleshooting

**EDIT - Further Research - Comments on Common Emitter Preamplifier**

[image]

https://sites.google.com/a/davidmorrin.com/www/home/trouble/transistors/amplifiers

The preamplifier stage in the circuit below has the basic structure of the CE shunt feedback amplifier. I still don't know how to design the gain from circuit analysis. In the intercom circuit below, after replacing Q1 with C1815 NPN transistor, an AC input signal of plus to minus 5mV 1kHz sine wave was applied at R1/C1. Collector voltage had DC component of 2.3 volts and AC component of 830mV peak to peak. The measured voltage gain is 830/10 = 83. My original questions below related to the DC bias conditions and purpose of the many additional capacitors besides the AC coupling caps at input and output.

**Context**

Sorry if image quality is poor. I may edit the circuit to improve the appearance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPI8Hc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Shown is the reverse engineered schematic for a vintage intercom. Missing are some output filter components (a resistor and capacitor in parallel with the 8 ohm speaker, a capactor across the terminals of the 16 ohm speaker) and a DPDT switch used to swap the small speakers as input/output devices.

This device functioned very well for decades. But now it does not function. I have repaired the on/off switch in the volume control and taken the DPDT switch out for the purpose of troubleshooting. I have buzzed each speaker with a 500 Hz tone.

The house has the 8 ohm speaker in the Master unit with all the components except the 16 ohm speaker. The 16 ohm speaker is connected remotely by about 300 feet of telephone hookup wire. The DPDT switch in the house is used to call the remote and allow the remote to respond but this configuration assumes the remote is input and the 8 ohm speaker is output.

**Schematic Comments**

Voltages shown are the DC bias conditions. DC voltages measured after inserting battery with 9.3 volts open circuit voltage. I think the battery may have excessive internal resistance due to measuring only 6.8 volts output in operation. I don't think it is due to high current flow out of the battery at this point but could re-check the current draw.

**Question 1**: I cannot find specifications for Q1 (536 F4A). I assume it is NPN and should have about 0.6 to 0.7 volts at the Base pin when the circuit is powered by 9 volt battery. The operating Base voltage is 0.004 volts. Is this evidence of a bad transistor or perhaps a bad capacitor?

**Question 2**: What is the purpose of R1, D1, C2, C3, C4, C6, C7, and C9?

The circuit works exceptionally well for 300 foot distance between remote speaker and master unit. It makes me wonder if the components in Question 2 are critical to the outstanding performance of this decades-old workhorse device.

**EDIT - Fresh Battery Measurements**

The first battery measures Voc = 9.3{V}.
Input current I = 3.3{mA}.

Fresh battery Voc = 9.44{V}. Input current I = 4.2{mA}.

| Tired Battery | Fresh Battery |
| --- | --- |
| Voc = 9.3 V | Voc = 9.44 V |
| Idraw = 3.3 mA | Idraw = 4.2 mA |
| Vtop = 6.8 V | Vtop = 9.3 V |
| Rs = 760 R | Rs = 33 R |
| VC6 = 5.8 V | VC6 = 7.94 V |
| VC4 = 2.6 V | VC4 = 3.74 V |
| Vbase = 0.004 V | Vbase = 0.005 V |
| VC10 = 3.5 V | VC10 = 4.8 V |

Rs is the internal source resistance of the battery. So the tired 9V battery definitely has large Rs! Simulator and theory predict 0.6 to 0.7 volts Vbase. Measurements show Vbase = 0.005 volts. I think the next step is to remove C2 and check Vbase for proper voltage; if not proper then maybe replace C1, Q1, etc. Time to desolder C2.

**EDIT - Replaced Q1 and Removed C2**

C2 was removed with no change in bias voltages. C2 measures open circuit and C = 1nF. I replaced Q1 with the pin compatible C1815 transistor with Hfe = 303. I put a 10mV peak to peak 500 Hz sine wave on the input of R1/C1 and measured about 7.5 volt peak to peak sine wave on the output with some phase shift. Vbase = 0.69 volts and, to my surprise, the voltage at the collector pin remained 2.6 volts. The output sine wave attenuates and eventually clips with an increase in frequency. Need to assemble everything to test for proper human voice bandwidth.

Comment: Either the Q1 is not a BJT transistor at all, or there is missing a a circuit that gives a base bias, as there is no way it can work with just base connected to a DC blocking capacitor.

Comment: You wrongly show R2 biasing the microphone instead of correctly biasing the base of the transistor. When R2 biases the base then the base voltage will; be about 0.65V but you measured almost no voltage on the base so maybe your multimeter is shoring the base to almost 0V. When R2 is connected to the base of the transistor then the transistor collector voltage will still be what you measured and the circuit should work fine. Maybe coupling capacitors C1, C5, C7 or c10 are open or maybe the volume control R7 is defective.

Comment: Most capacitors you mentioned prevent interference from radio and TV signals.

Comment: @Justme I corrected the schematic to show C1 as an input coupling capacitor to the Base of Q1 (previously it was shown incorrectly between R2 and the Base pin). I have simulated this circuit in MicroCap 12, but since there is no 386 chip in the library, I used a 200 gain voltage controlled voltage source instead. The simulated input of 500 Hz sine tone 20mV peak to peak produces simulated output of roughly 4 volts peak to peak. So I think the BJT is NPN and either C2 is shorted or the Base-Emitter diode is shorted. I did not simulate voltage drop due to Rs. Q1 collector pin at 3.9 V simulated.

Comment: @Audioguru I corrected the schematic per your comment. I built a similar LM386 some time ago which produced loud feedback noise even when input and output speakers were about 20 feet apart. I could not figure out how to reduce feedback but that is a different matter. In this application the little input speaker has to send power 300 feet over twisted pair and yet the device functions very well without noise or lack of volume. The power source used to be a 9 volt DC adapter not a 9 volt battery. It will go back in service if I fix it. May replace Q1 or faulty capacitor(s) or JRC386 with LM386.

Comment: Does Rs represent the internal resistance of your battery rather than being a discrete component? If your battery voltage is dropping from 9.3 V off-load to 6.8 V on-load the first thing to try is a fresh battery then retake your voltage measurements. Rule 1 of fault-finding on battery-operated equipment is to fit a fresh battery.

Comment: @Graham Nye The simulation shows the circuit should work, with some amplitude attenuation, even if the input voltage drops to 6 volts. So the tired battery might be enough to get some signal output when stimulated by a function generator and check output on oscilloscope. You give the proper advice. In an edit I have produced a table comparing the tired battery to the fresh battery.

Comment: The battery is fine since the transistor is conducting. But the ZERO base voltage is the serious problem. A simple test of the LM386 power amplifier was not done by touching the input and hearing the buzzing. Acoustical feedback howling is normal when a microphone can hear its own signal from a speaker. FEEDBACK is when a sound comes out of the speaker, goes back into the microphone and goes around and around.